# c# how to create cycle via timer?

Tags: c#, timer, cycle

How to make the cycle, running up for 30 seconds? After 30 seconds, the cycle must be repeated with changing one variable(i++).
P.S. I've never used a timer and I need a detailed solution.

Comment: Read the docs. Study the examples. Try it for yourself.

Comment: @DrKoch if points weren't so addictive I'd be writing my first million dollar computer game

Comment: @Ewan ever got points from a 3 rep user?

Comment: just as long as i don't get down-voted for my dodgy use of volatile

Answer (score 0):

the microsoft example seems pretty good. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

here is a cut down version, ive set it for 3 sec rather than 30 so you can verify the result

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            example e = new example();
            e.timer();
            Console.Read();
        }

        public class example
        {
            public volatile int i;
            public void timer()
            {
                TimerCallback tcb = callback;
                Timer t = new Timer(tcb, i, 3000, 3000);
            }

            public void callback(object state)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(this.i);
                this.i++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```